# Wordpress image galleries using categories

Tags: image, wordpress, plugins, gallery, categories

I'm looking for a WordPress plugin which makes it possible to create categories and put some galleries in that category.

For example: I'm going to my photo album page. On that page there are all my categories by viewing some thumbnails (e.g. categorie 1, categorie 2, categorie 3). Then I can go to one of those categories which contains all my galleries (e.g. categorie 1 cointains gallery 1a, gallery 1b, gallery 1c. Categorie 2 contains gallery 2a, gallery 2b, gallery 2c.)

Is that possible to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this plugin: NextGEN Gallery http://wordpress.org/plugins/nextgen-gallery/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this plugin earlier but I can't figure out on how to setup this plugin to achieve what I want.

Comment: WP Photo Album Plus : http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-photo-album-plus/ is also a good option. Read documentation of both plugins carefully, then it will be easy to integrate.

Comment: You can't do this in NextGEN Gallery. or if you can it is not straightforward and requires more explanation